# Query for banks in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Using http://dbpedia.org/sparql, I want to receive the geographic coordinates of all bank buildings. [The list of classes](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/) tells me that I should query for `Bank`.

Yet, the following code yields nothing:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?lat ?long
WHERE {
[]
 rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Bank ;
 geo:lat ?lat ;
 geo:long ?long ;
 rdfs:label ?label.
      FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) 
}
```

If instead I query for any sibling to `Bank`, (e.g. `Brewery` or `LawFirm`), I see at least some results. What's wrong with above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into a dbpedia page for a bank, you can see that instead on `rdf:type`, banks have a property `dbpedia-owl:industry` that has `dbpedia:Bank` ([Refah bank](http://dbpedia.org/page/Refah_Bank)) or `dbpedia:Financial_services` ([Cyprus bank](http://dbpedia.org/page/Bank_of_Cyprus)) as a value. So if you rewrite your query as the following, you will get some results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?lat ?long
WHERE {
    [] dbpedia-owl:industry dbpedia:Bank ;
    geo:lat ?lat ;
    geo:long ?long ;
    rdfs:label ?label.
    FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) 
}
```

If you add `dbpedia:Financial_services`, other organisations such as [London stock exchange](http://dbpedia.org/page/London_Stock_Exchange_Group) will also appear:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?bank
WHERE {
    ?bank dbpedia-owl:industry ?place ;
    geo:lat ?lat ;
    geo:long ?long ;
    rdfs:label ?label.
    FILTER (?place in (dbpedia:Financial_services, dbpedia:Bank) &&
    LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) 
}
```

Again, by examining the London stock exchange, you can see that there is a product property that separates these financial institutions. So this will give you banks, but it might not cover all the banks available:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?lat ?long
WHERE {
    [] dbpedia-owl:industry ?place ;
    geo:lat ?lat ;
    geo:long ?long ;
    rdfs:label ?label;
    dbpedia-owl:product ?product.
    FILTER ( ?place in (dbpedia:Financial_services, dbpedia:Bank) 
    && ?product in (dbpedia:Bank, dbpedia:Private_banking, dbpedia:Professional_Banking, dbpedia:Retail_banking, dbpedia:Investment_banking, dbpedia:Commercial_bank)
    && LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "en")) 
} ORDER BY DESC(COUNT(DISTINCT ?product))
```

Comment: I just tried to co run your quries again but I keep getting the error `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 5: Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia-owl' before 'dbpedia:Bank'` (for the first query).

Comment: They have changed the standard namespaces http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl. I'll edit the post.

Comment: They have also removed lat and long from couple of answers that I got out. you can get `location` out, but that's it.

Comment: Not even that is everyhwere (in fact, it's complete gone from places like http://dbpedia.org/page/Deutsche_Bundesbank). You probably don't know why this happened and where I could complain about that?

Comment: There was a new release of dbpedia I think about a month back. I have the whole set loaded in a triplestore, and I think it is completely removed since the wiki pages have also lacks them. Security reason, perhaps?

Comment: That's very bad news for me. What's strange: the wiki pages still display geocoordinates.